# Rails : undefined method `exists?' for AWS::S3::S3Object:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using the aws-sdk gem and trying to verify if a file uploaded to a bucket exists.
I'm also using Paperclip 2.7.

This method seems to not work:

```
if record.image and AWS::S3::S3Object.exists? record.image, "mybucket-dev"
```

I think AWS::S3::S3Object.exists? was a method from old gem aws-s3 ?

What method can I use to test if the file is present in the bucket ?

In fact, the real path I want to check is something like that:

```
record.image.to_file(:tiny).path
```

(the tiny version of my image)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
AWS::S3.new.buckets["bucket"].objects["file path on s3"].exists?
```

The above code will return `true` if the file exists else returns `false`.

For your future reference please refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html# 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try see this document

http://rubydoc.info/github/stesla/fog/Fog/AWS/S3:head_object
not sure it help, this is using Fog

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

obj = AWS::S3::Bucket.find("bucket_name")

obj.objects[object_name].exists?

This would return true or false.

OR

AWS::S3::S3Object.exists? "path to file", "bucket_name"

Answer (score 0):

Aws::S3::Object.new(region:'ap-southeast-1', credentials: 'cred', key: 'key', bucket_name: 'bucket').exists?